# How to show that $f(z) = z^2 + 1$ intersects the line through the roots of $f(z) = 0$ in ComplexPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, complex

I have plotted the complex function $f(z) = z^2+1$ by using the following code:

> ComplexPlot3D[z^2+1, {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I}]

However, I want to show that $z^2+1$ intersects the line $\Re(z) = 0$. The z-coordinates of intersection are: $z = i$ and $z = -i$, because the roots can easily be found by factorising the function: $f(z) = (z+i)(z-i)$. How do I show that the function $f(z)$ intersects the line $\Re(z) = 0$ graphically in this 3D ComplexPlot?

My main objective is to show that if $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x) = x^2 +1$ ($x\in\mathbb{R}$), then the function doesn't intersect with $y = 0$ (or $f(x) = 0$), but it does intersect with $\Re(z) = 0$ if $f: \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is defined by $f(z) = z^2 + 1$ ($z\in\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: What do you mean by "the line $f(z) = 0$"? If $f(z) = z^2+1$, then the graph of $f(z) = 0$ is not a line.

Comment: Normally, the function doesn't intersect with y=0. However, it does if you take complex numbers into account. So I mean that specific line, which it intersects in $(i, 0)$ and $(-i, 0)$

Comment: @mjw Well, the question has already been answered, look at that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[z_] = z^2 + 1;

ComplexPlot3D[f[z], {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {Re[z], Im[z], Abs[f[z]]}),
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

`f[z] == 0` is not a line but rather two points.

```
pts = {Re[#], Im[#], 0} & /@ (z /. Solve[f[z] == 0, z])

(* {{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}} *)
```

To see this graphically, limit the `PlotRange` and reverse the z-axis.

```
Show[
 ComplexPlot3D[f[z], {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {Re[z], Im[z], Abs[f[z]]}),
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.1},
  ClippingStyle -> None,
  PlotPoints -> 125,
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Reverse"}],
 Graphics3D[{Black, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point /@ pts}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To show the line that passes through `pts`

```
Show[
 ComplexPlot3D[f[z], {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {Re[z], Im[z], Abs[f[z]]}),
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.1},
  ClippingStyle -> None,
  PlotPoints -> 125,
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Reverse"}],
 Graphics3D[{Black, Thick, InfiniteLine[pts]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one question, why does the reversed image look different compared to the first image? Isn't it supposed to be the same function?

Comment: @Stallmp - It is the same function; however, at the `PlotRange` of the first plot you cannot see the details of the "dimples". Look at `Manipulate[
 ComplexPlot3D[f[z], {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I}, 
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {Re[z], Im[z], Abs[f[z]]}), 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {0, zmax},
  PlotPoints -> 125,
  ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Reverse"},
  ClippingStyle -> None],
 {{zmax, 45}, 1, 45, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 4):

**Using just built-in functions**

```
Show[
  ComplexPlot3D[z^2 + 1, {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I}, ColorFunction -> "LightTerrain"], 
  ComplexPlot3D[0, {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I}, ColorFunction -> "LightTerrain", PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]],
  Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, Line[{{0, -5, 0}, {0, 5, 0}}]}],
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Re[z], Im[z], w}, Boxed -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {-10, 50}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}]
```

[image: A complex plot in 3D]

Probably a different viewpoint would show better what's going on.

**Using David Park's *Presentations* add-on**

This add-on allows, among many other features, working directly with complex graphics objects and complex functions; it includes functions such as `ComplexCartesianSurface` that predate the functions such as `ComplexPlot3D` introduced in *Mathematica* 12.0. (To obtain Park's add-on, see: [Where is David Park's Mathematica site?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1770/where-is-david-parks-mathematica-site).)

Since *Presentations* does not include a function that maps points in the complex plane to points in space, let's define a simple version of one:

```
complexTo3D[pts_, z_] := Append[z] /@ ReIm[pts]
```

The function:

```
f[z_] := z^2 + 1
```

Load Park's add-on:

```
<< Presentations`
```

And create the 3D graphic:

```
With[{zmin = -1 - 1.75 I, zmax = 1 + 1.75 I},
  zeros = z /. Solve[f[z] == 0, z];
  Draw3DItems[
    {
     Opacity[0.85],
     ComplexCartesianSurface[f[z], Abs, {z, zmin, zmax},
       PlotPoints -> 50,
       Mesh -> 12,
       MeshFunctions ->
         {Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Re[f[u + I v]]],
          Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Im[f[u + I v]]]},
       MeshStyle -> {White, LightGray},
       ColorFunction -> 
         Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, ColorData["RedGreenSplit"][Rescale[Arg[f[u + I v]], {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}]]],
       ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
     ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Reverse"}
     ],
     Opacity[0.3],
     ComplexCartesianSurface[0, Abs, {z, zmin, zmax},
       Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> LighterGray,
       ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Reverse"},
       PlotTheme -> "Classic"
     ],
     PointSize[Large], Red, Point /@ complexTo3D[zeros, 0]
   },
   BaseStyle -> {12, Bold},
   PlotRange -> {-4, 0.75},
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Re[z], Im[z], Abs[f[z]]},
   Ticks -> False,
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.75}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Zeros of z^2 + 1 using Presentations add-on]

The mesh on the graph of $\lvert f(z)\rvert$ is formed by level curves of $\Re(f(z)$ and $\Im(f(z)$, while the coloring is obtained from $\arg(f(z))$. (This may be visual overload!)

One could doubtless experiment with the various colors to obtain a more informative, or at least more pleasing, image.
Note that I've exploited the enhancement from @BobHanlon's answer of reversing the direction of the *f*(*z*)-axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I was looking for indeed.

Comment: @murray can you provide the example using presentations? And a link to the add-on on David Park’s site would be beneficial also. Nice job!